# Can Monitor mode and internet connection work together?

Tags: wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, kali-linux, wifi-driver, network-monitoring

Im using raspberry Pi 3 with linux Kali installed , trying to capture all the packets in my WLAN network.

Now,to do that I need to get in monitor mode, since the R.PI3 built in chip has no monitor mode (BroadCom) I bought the TP LINK WN722N which has monitor mode and Pentesting capabilities.

Once connnected to the wifi, im getting it into monitor mode , killing all disturbing services and then I lose internet connection, using this 3 methods:

1. `ifconfig wlan1 down
   iwconfig wlan1 mode monitor
   ifconfig wlan1 up`

after a few seconds the connection is automatically unpluggs and managed mode is acivated.

2.`airmon-ng check kill 
airmon-ng start wlan1`

after a few sec internet connection is off but monitor mode is on ( so what is it monitoring??)

3.
`ip link set wlan1 down
iw dev wlan1 set type monitor
ip link set wlan1 up
iw dev #to check status`

goes into monitor mode but lose internet connection.

I even tried restarting Network-Manager service, didn't work and force me back to Managed mode.

I read somewhere that not all Wifi adapters can communicate both ways so I can only receive packets but not send them and thats why I have no internet connection when im monitoring, but what is it monitoring if its not connected to any wifi???

Maybe I should download its drivers and compile?any idea where can I get those? I just "plugged and played" it.

Im trying to figure this problem out, any help?

Comment: Just from the start of your question: You're not even monitoring your LAN but instead your WLAN. As for what it's monitoring: Probably the general 2.4 GHz band. It would just pass on any package. If you are using `airmon-ng` why not check what information is available?

Comment: @Seth Yes my bad its WLAN & what do you mean check what information is available?

Comment: Well from what I understand `airmon-ng` is a suite of tools that should capitalize on the information that is available through that monitor mode. So did you try to use those tools to see which information you can actually gather that way?

Comment: @Seth I just went through aircrack-ng's bunch of tools and guides, its a good tool to crack WPA/WEP AP but not to capture packets. I was initially using airmon-ng software to see this packets but thats not working. I hope someone could clear this up for me, how to use aircrack to capture packets and their payloads if its even possible

Comment: Did you try Wireshark?